# Coding user interfaces vs. Drag and Drop

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am currently studying Computer Science in Denmark on second semester, and so far we've only been using the built-in Drag and Drop GUI builder from Netbeans.

We're going to start working on our next exam project in a few weeks, and I've wondered if I'd better start learning to program them without the Drag and Drop.

In the real world, would it be better to code GUIs on your own, or is the Drag and Drop editors mature enough to be used in practice?

Comment: Voting to close: Essentially unanswerable as it is a very subjective question: for a lot of basic UI things I personally prefer visual construction (what you call drag and drop), but I know that a lot of people swear by hand coding the user interface (and I admit: for more complex things hand coding is often required)

Comment: Hand coding GUIs is better when the situation is not so complex and moreover it would make you learn the inner details.

Comment: My personal preference always go for hand-written UI (for simple and complex UI's). Yet, if you want to use GUI-builders, you will produce clean code and proper interfaces only if you understand how Swing works in details. To learn how Swing works in details, hand-written code is quite a good academy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I would say to just use whatever works.  Drag and drop GUI editors are totally for wimps :), but having designed tons of GUIs "by hand," I can say that I have been tempted to create a drag and drop editor myself.  It's very tedious to program the GUI layout in the code, but I would strongly suggest that you become familiar with doing it.  It's always important to understand any code for which you are responsible from the ground up.  If something breaks, you should always be able to find it and know exactly why it's broken.  Creating a program with a "black box" can be convenient until it starts to have problems, in which case you might wish you did the leg work yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn to ride a bike faster with training wheels. However, you will be able to ride that bike much faster without them.

GUI builders will get your first few GUI's up and running quicker, but eventually you will build them quicker and better if you learn by hand.

Also, doing it by hand means that your not tied to any one particular GUI builder should your company decide to change IDE's on you.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know how to if you need to. Anything difficult will require coding, not drag and drop.